# Scroll in one item is affecting another item in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

In my page I've a carousel and four items inside of that carousel.

All items have some big lists and scrolling in one item is automatically scrolling other item.

I don't want other items to be scrolling automatically they should be at their position until scrolled, How to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>          
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
           <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>             
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're scrolling on the web page, not inside carousel...

Here is one way, just have to set a `max-height` to the carousel items.

**CSS**:

```
.carousel .item {max-height:300px;overflow:auto;}
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/c0k8PpJ6PP

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  .carousel .item {max-height:300px;overflow:auto;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>          
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
         <p>Item 1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item 2</p>
         <p>Item2</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
           <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>             
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
         <p>Item 3</p>
         <p>Item3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
         <p>Item 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```